# SQL and conditional logic on Where

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very simple SQL search query as follows.

```
$sql = 
"
SELECT *
FROM suppliers
WHERE                       
product_categories LIKE '%$product_categories1%'                        
AND agentid=?????
";
```

In the part of the query where `agentid=???` I need to get the following conditionality to work.

If some `$var` is (say) 1 then `agentid !=' '`
If same `$var` is (say) 2  then `agentid =' '`

The purpose of this query is . .. `if !=''` the query returns ALL rows where there is an agentid value `(!='')` or SQL returns no rows at all if agentid is set to `(=' ')`.

My problem is how to write the SQL to introduce this simple condition?

PS I am aware of the `<>` sql alternative.

Comment: SQL-->  IS NOT NULL or IS NULL , not != or = ' '

Comment: use php to assign a value to an `$agent_id` variable before the query, then use the variable in the query. That way your `$agent_id` variable will already have the expected value according to the condition.

Comment: But can `$var` either be 1 OR 2? Or there can be other values?

Comment: so tell me how to assign a value of !=. Obviously one can use a conditional php statement to set a var and then assign it to agentid. That wasnt the question

Comment: Alon ... $var is arbitrary. It simply used as a way of switching agentid='' or agentid!='' The values could be anything, True false etc

Comment: @WChris Then you have an answer that look fine, but I strongly suggest to make a safe queries using PDO - Read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection and then this  http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to build your SQL query conditionally.  You can use control statements to change what your output SQL is:

```
// ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS sanitize your input.  Use prepared statements to
// build safe queries (see first comment under this answer).  This example
// of using msqli_escape_string is NOT considered "secure", but is used in
// this context to highlight the importance of sanitization.
$product_categories1 = msqli_escape_string($product_categories1);

if ($var == 'condition') {
    $condition = "agentid IS NOT NULL";
}
else {
    $condition = "agentid IS NULL";
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM suppliers
        WHERE product_categories LIKE '%$product_categories1%'                        
        AND $condition";
```

Comment: Brilliant. The bit I was unware of is that you could do this------>  AND $condition

Comment: @AlonEitan I'm aware, hence the comment about prepared statements.  But I'll ammend the answer to put more emphasis on using prepared statements instead.

Comment: upvoted for that little bit of additional inspiration, Thank you

Comment: @Wrinn Cool. When the code is safe (and not only works) then i'll happily upvote, because I don't want the OP to leave SO with bad practice, they may one day use it wrong and then they can get their website hacked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
if ($var == 1)
    $where = "agentid != ''";
else
    $where = "agentid like ''";

$sql = 
" SELECT *
    FROM suppliers
  WHERE                       
    product_categories LIKE '%$product_categories1%'                        
  AND $where ";
```

Comment: Although your answer seem correct (based on what the OP wrote), I wouldn't upvote it because of the sql injection danger with this code. Sorry

Comment: And `agentid == ''` is not a valid sql syntax

Comment: Wow does that work in mysql Let me try it Filipe. Vote up if it works

Comment: `LIKE` should be used with patterns. Use `=` to compare with a literal string.